# ExtJs Gridpanel store refresh

Tags: extjs

I am binding ExtJs Gridpanel from database and add "Delete" button below my gridpanel. By using the delete button handler, I have deleted selected record on gridpanel. But, after deleting, the grid does not refresh (it is deleted from database but shows on grid because of no refresh).

How can I refresh grid after delete handler ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try refreshing the view:

```
Ext.getCmp('yourGridId').getView().refresh();
```

Comment: this seems to not work. 80% of my rows just disappear

Answer (score 13):

reload the ds to refresh grid.

```
ds.reload();
```

Comment: This works! getView().refresh() seems to have no effect.

Comment: Refreshing view still works with the local data. If you only delete the record on server and not locally, refresh will not help you.

Answer (score 11):

```
grid.store = store;
store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 20} });
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: Are you sure you should call grid.view.refresh() right after the asynchronous load?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similiar problem. All I needed to do was type `store.load();` in the delete handler. There was no need to subsequently type `grid.getView().refresh();`.

Instead of all this you can also type `store.remove(record)` in the delete handler; - this ensures that the deleted record no longer shows on the grid.

Answer (score 4):

try this `grid.getView().refresh();`

Comment: He answered this one 1 min late than the accepted answer, probably they were typing at the same time, but they had different internet speeds.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use store.remove than model.destroy.
Click handler for that button may looks like this:

```
destroy: function(button) {
    var grid = button.up('grid');
    var store = grid.getStore();
    var selected = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

    if (selected && selected.length==1) {
        store.remove(selected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grid.getStore().reload({
  callback: function(){
    grid.getView().refresh();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Combination of Dasha's and MMT solutions:

```
  Ext.getCmp('yourGridId').getView().ds.reload();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach in 3.4 (don't know if this is proper Ext): You can have a delete handler like this, assuming every row has a 'delete' button.

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
    var id = rec.get('id');
    // some DELETE/GET ajax callback here...
    // pass in 'id' var or some key
    // inside success
    grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Refresh Grid Store

`Ext.getCmp('GridId').getStore().reload();`

This will reload the grid store and get new data.