# How to refresh the data in an ExtJS Grid without reloading

Tags: extjs

How to update a grid data in extjs  without page refresh ? Please give me a full working code I am newbie in extjs . Here is my code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'register.cfm',
    method:'POST',
    params  : { data : JSON.stringify(form.getValues()) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
         win.hide();
         //var str = JSON.stringify(response.responseText);
         var obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
         if (obj==1) {
            var values = form.getFieldValues ();
            store.add(form.getFieldValues())
        } else {
            (here i need to show updated values in the grid without refresh)
        }
   },
   failure : function(response){}
}); // eof ajax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue here is that your manually trying to update the store via ajax.

The store should be pre-conifugred to work with your endpoint and able to update itself. If your using ExtJS 4+ you can use Store Filters as shown in the [Store Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store).

If you are using ExtJs 3 then you should update the params on the store and let it handle the request and updating of the records.

For example (code not fully tested, may need some slight changes):

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore().load({
    params: {
        data: JSON.stringify(form.getValues())
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't even post the name of your grid I cannot provide you more than

```
Ext.getCmp('yourGridId').getView().refresh();
```

which should be called after

```
store.add(form.getFieldValues())
```

(did you miss a **`;`** ?)

[See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815497/extjs-gridpanel-store-refresh)

Comment: actually the if else condition is because if a new data is added   then "store.add(form.getFieldValues())" addes the value in the grid, otherwise update it. This is the point where i am stuck how to update. My grid name is "myGrid"

Comment: sorry but this didnt helped out .